# How to remove lines in a text file containing three columns based on a number in the third column?

Tags: python, text, notepad++, batch-processing

I am new to coding this kind of problem, I am open to the simplest tool or solution. None of the tools I know how to use seem to be able to open the file. I would prefer to avoid excel as I would like to eventually batch the process. I have tried for some time and been unable to do this simple task automatically. I am sure there is a simple solution.

I simply want to find the instances where `column 3` below the `__` contains something other than 3, where it contains something other than 3 remove the line.

Here is an example of my data contained in a text file with an extension that is not `.txt`:

```
 0.0004882812500000 136
 0.000000      5850  __
 4.674316   1307778   3
 9.699219   2707354   3
14.932617   4165002   3
20.051270   5590690   3
24.809082   6915874   3
24.815430   6917642   2
29.786621   8302258   3
35.123535   9788738   3
35.123535   9788738   3
40.535645  11296162   1
```

I need to remove the lines that do not contain a 3 in the third column. I am new to programming so I am open to suggestions of simplest tool. I attempted Python, but my knowledge is too limited.
I also tried Notepad++ with a search and replace, and I have added the `Python` add-on, but I don't know where to start.

Apologies if I have posted this wrong.

Comment: It did not parse past the __ . I have just noticed one of my test files was empty below the __. Let me delete my question and come back when I am stuck again. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

**It is not clear whether you need a scripted answer to rerun the process or can use a manual process to do the manipulation** (re-read your post and see that you would like to eventually script this out...regex should still give you a starting point even if you move past notepad++), but here is a quick and dirty scenario using Notepad++ assuming that your sample data is representative (2-digit numbers in the 3rd column will take another element in regex):

1. In notepad++ with your data showing, do 'Mark' (ctrl-H, then tab for 'Mark')
2. Select Search Mode 'Regular Expression' and check 'bookmark line'
3. Use the following regex:  ^\s{0,1}(\S+\s+){2}[012456789]$
4. Click 'Mark All'
5. Menu 'Search' / Bookmark / Cut Bookmarked Lines

Regex meaning:

- From start of line (the caret)
- Match zero or one space characters
- Then (2) instances of one or more non-space characters followed by one or more space characters
- Then any digit which is not a '3'
- and anchored to the end of the line (with the $), which may be overkill :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: regex used in the search 'Find what:' field resulted in 0 Matches.

Comment: Hmmm...I actually tested the solution after scraping your sample data as posted in the question into NP++.  Are you certain the Search Mode is set to 'Regular expression' and, if so, do you get the same response if you scrape the values from this question (thinking maybe there are additional characters in the file that maybe did not make it to the sample data here)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do this in python here is a starting point:

```
linesWith3 = []  # Store lines with 3 in last column
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:  # Open file
    for line in f.readlines():
         cols = line.split()  # Split into array of columns
         if "3" in cols[2]:
              linesWith3.append(line)  # Store line
with open("file2.txt", "w") as f:  # Write array to file
    for line in linesWith3:
        f.write(line+'\n')
```